# How do I uninstall only one of my multiple Watchman Versions?

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, versioning, watchman

I am having issues with my watchman while working on a React Native / Expo project and I think it's cause I may have multiple versions. This is the information I can find about Watchman through my terminal:

```
    ~npm watchman
    9.6.6
    ~watchman -v
    2023.05.22.00
    ~which -a watchman
    /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
    /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
    ~echo $PATH
    /opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:
    /usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/
    usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple
    /usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/
    codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/
    com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:
    /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/
    usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/jennyestes/Library/Android/sdk/
    platform-tools:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:
    /Users/jennyestes/.npm-global/bin
    ~npx expo-cli doctor
    WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the versioned Expo CLI (npx expo).
    Warning: You are using an old version of watchman (vHEAD-2209b1c).

    It is recommend to always use the latest version, or at least v4.6.0.

    If you are using homebrew, try:
    brew uninstall watchman; brew install watchman
    Warning: Invalid version react-native@0.69.9 for expo sdkVersion 44.0.0. 
    Use react-native@0.64.3
```

I look forward to a kind soul out there helping me out with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Give `brew reinstall watchman` a try (which is equivalent to `brew uninstall watchman; brew install watchman`), it would handle the multiple versions of `brew` installed `watchman`.

Answer (score 0):

Entering npm watchman gave me my npm package version and not another Watchman version. Thus, I only have one Watchman version installed.